# Url.Action not outputting URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using Url.Action so that I can create more complex HTML links as ActionLink doesn't allow HTML inside them. Example:

```
 <a class="uiButton" href="@Url.Action("Areas","Organisations","Manage","Create")" title="New Organisation">
                    <span class="icon organisations-new">New Organisation</span>
                </a>
```

However the URL doesn't appear in the **`href`**? Any ideas why ? :/

Comment: I get an empty link like `href=""`

Comment: what happens when you pull the call out?

Comment: What do you mean by pulling the call out?

Comment: This is normally an issue with routing - could you please post your routing code?

Comment: context.MapRoute(
                "Organisations_new",
                "Organisations/New",
                new { controller = "Manage", action = "Create" }
            );

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505232.aspx) overload of Url.Action

```
public string Action(
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    string protocol
)
```

And you are definitely using it wrong (no protocol like "Create"). Use [any of appropriate overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action.aspx) for you. For example, if you've got `OrganizationsController` and `Create` action, this code will be enough:

```
@Url.Action("Create", "Organisations")
```

If you want to route to another area, supply routeValues object like `new {Area = "anotherAreaName"}`.

```
@Url.Action("Create", "Manage", new {Area = "Organizations"})
```

This will route to Organizations area, Create action on ManageController

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had an empty string because **"area" parameter was wrong**.