# url.action not returning an url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco7, url.action

my url.action wont return a href..

i have seen this question: [Url.Action not outputting URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597156/url-action-not-outputting-url)

but it did not seem to answer my question since i only use an action name and a controller name...

this is my anchor:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("HomePage", "HomePage")" class="logo"><strong>News page / blog</strong> by Name.</a>
```

it just returns an empty href=""...

my controller name is HomePageController, and my ActionResult is HomePage().

**EDIT:** i am also using umbraco on the project.

Comment: Is there an `Area` involved?

Comment: im sorry, i do not know what Area is ?

Comment: might be because of umbraco, that it isn't possible..

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? why are you using that syntax if you have umbraco?

Comment: Is that a custom controller? Normally in Umbraco you wouldn't use Url.Action, except for custom stuff.

Comment: yes it is a custom controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom controllers in Umbraco should inherit from Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController.

If you were to set up your controller like this:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Web.Mvc;

public class HomePageController : SurfaceController
{
    public ActionResult HomePage()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

@Url.Action("HomePage", "HomePage") would then return "/umbraco/surface/homepage/homepage".